# Modifying XML File being install by WiX during Install

Tags: xml, wix

I'm working on a WiX installer that needs to modify one of the XML Files being installed depending on a condition chosen during install. Is there a way to do this during the initial install?

I've tried using XMLFile and was getting an error about the file not existing. I'm wondering if using XMLFile is the correct way to do this and I just had the file path wrong maybe.

Comment: How are you referring to the file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the path to xml file is wrong, when you run the msi the error message includes the path. This will help in fixing the path, or refer to verbose log file ( msiexec /i  /*lvx ).

Refer https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/xml/ for example on using XmlFile